# Command to run Theano on GPU (windows)

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, cmd, theano

I talk about the tutorial here http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/using_gpu.html

The code I use

```
from theano import function, config, shared, sandbox
import theano.tensor as T
import numpy
import time

vlen = 10 * 30 * 768  # 10 x #cores x # threads per core
iters = 1000

rng = numpy.random.RandomState(22)
x = shared(numpy.asarray(rng.rand(vlen), config.floatX))
f = function([], T.exp(x))
print(f.maker.fgraph.toposort())
t0 = time.time()
for i in range(iters):
    r = f()
t1 = time.time()
print("Looping %d times took %f seconds" % (iters, t1 - t0))
print("Result is %s" % (r,))
if numpy.any([isinstance(x.op, T.Elemwise) for x in f.maker.fgraph.toposort()]):
    print('Used the cpu')
else:
    print('Used the gpu')
```

At section [Testing Theano with GPU](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/using_gpu.html#testing-theano-with-gpu):
There are some command line which set Theano flag to run on cpu or gpu. The problem is I have no idea to put these command in.

I have try on windows cmd

```
THEANO_FLAGS=mode=FAST_RUN,device=gpu,floatX=float32 python theanogpu_example.py
```

then I get

```
'THEANO_FLAGS' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

[image: t1]

However, I am able to run the code, on cpu using the command

```
python theanogpu_example.py
```

[image: t2]

I want to run the code on GPU, what should I do (with these command in the [tutorial](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/using_gpu.html#testing-theano-with-gpu))?

**SOLUTION** 

Thanks to @Blauelf about the idea of windows environment variable.
However, the param has to be separated

```
set THEANO_FLAGS="mode=FAST_RUN"  & set THEANO_FLAGS="device=gpu" & set THEANO_FLAGS="floatX=float32" & python theanogpu_example.py
```

Comment: Multiple `set THEANO_FLAGS=` lines will replace the previous content (that's why scripts sometimes contain code like `set PATH=%PATH%;C:\myDir`, where `%PATH%` is automatically replaced by the previous value), so in that command line, only the last `set` will actually have an effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the docs](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/config.html), `THEANO_FLAGS` is an environment variable. So as you're on Windows, you might want to change

```
THEANO_FLAGS=mode=FAST_RUN,device=gpu,floatX=float32 python theanogpu_example.py
```

into

```
set THEANO_FLAGS="mode=FAST_RUN,device=gpu,floatX=float32" & python theanogpu_example.py
```

Comment: That part also sounds interesting: [Configure THEANO for GPU use](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html#configure-theano-for-gpu-use)